# Rust custom deserialize to BigInt

Tags: rust

I'm new in rust, and have a hard time with deserialize and i am not fully understand how it is work.
I trying to warp BigInt and make my own serialize/deserialize.

i want is to serialize BigNum to string with the fully number
and desrialzie back to bigNum

this is my code:

```
use num_bigint::BigInt;
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Serialize};
use std::ops::Deref;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct BigNum(BigInt);

impl Deref for BigNum {
    type Target = BigInt;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl Serialize for BigNum {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: serde::Serializer,
    {
        serializer.serialize_str(&self.deref().to_string())
    }
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for BigNum {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let num = String::deserialize(deserializer)?
            .parse::<BigInt>()
            .unwrap();
        Ok(BigNum(num))
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
#[test]
fn test_bignum() {
    let element = "1333333333333333333333333326766666666666666663124";
    let tuple: BigNum = serde_json::from_str(element).unwrap();
}
```

i don't understand why when i running the test i getting this error:

```
Error("invalid type: floating point `1333333333333333300000000000000000000000000000000`, expected a string", line: 1, column: 49)'
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just deriving `Serialize` and `Deserialize` for `BigNum`?

Comment: @isaactfa Presumably `BigInt` does not implement those traits, which is the purpose of the `BigNum` newtype.

Comment: `num_bigint` optionally depends on `serde`, So I'd expect that `BigInt`  does actually impelement those traits if you enable the `serde` feature on `num_bigint`? (You'd need `#[serde(transparent)]` though.)

Comment: @cdhowie But [it](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/struct.BigInt.html#impl-Deserialize%3C%27de%3E) [does](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/struct.BigInt.html#impl-Serialize). Unless OP is using a different crate.

Comment: @isaactfa They are using a different crate (`num_bigint`).

Comment: @Caesar Ah, interesting. The impl doesn't show up in the docs, presumably because it's conditional on a feature. Unfortunate.

Comment: @Caesar It's worth noting that the crate's implementation writes out the internal structure of the BigInt value. Since JSON is supposed to be consumable by humans, OP's approach of serializing it as a string might actually be preferred, even if it has more overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your serde implementations deal with strings, which *is correct* because JSON floats don't have the precision necessary to exactly store such a large number.  However, the input you have in `element` is a JSON numeric literal, not a JSON string.  You need to alter this input so that it's a JSON string:

```
let element = "\"1333333333333333333333333326766666666666666663124\"";
```

With this change, the test passes.